# use stty command to enable remapping ctrl+v

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, cygwin, clipboard, stty

Searching around, I found that `stty -ixon` enables remapping of <kbd>C-q</kbd> and <kbd>C-s</kbd>(such as in `~/.inputrc`).

Now I also want to remap <kbd>C-v</kbd>(to `paste-from-clipboard`, the default <kbd>S-Ins</kbd> feels awkward). With `stty -a` showing `lnext = ^V;`, I think `stty` has another option to enable this. I can find definitions to those options but they are hard to understand, or to find the one I want.

Also, I'm using a cygwin terminal if it matters.

---

Proof on *the answer lies in `stty`*:

- binding <kbd>C-a</kbd> to `paste-from-clipboard` in cygwin's `.inputrc` works
- binding <kbd>C-a</kbd> to `backward-char` on a Ubuntu 14.04.2 works
- binding <kbd>C-v</kbd> to `backward-char` on a Ubuntu 14.04.2 fails

So `paste-from-clipboard` is a command added by cygwin to its bash, which can be bound to keys the same way as e.g. `backward-char`.

Comment: Regarding your question update, I don't know what you think you're proving, but you seem to be confused. Bindings in `.inputrc` are not related to the ones configured via `stty`. `stty` configures the terminal driver, `.inputrc` configures bash and other programs that use the readline library. And copy-paste is provided by yet another entity, the terminal emulator.

Comment: Psst!  Gilles.  The interaction results from readline reading the terminal special characters and automatically (re-)binding actions to the various characters.  See http://superuser.com/questions/705807/#comment901053_705893

Comment: @JdeBP Works great! To be sure, setting this option doesn't affect those key bindings I don't modify in `.inputrc`, right? And please post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Gilles In case you missed the above...

Comment: @JdeBP Yes, readline uses this for things like determining whether ^? is backslash or delete. But stty doesn't say anything about copy-paste.

Answer (score 1):

`stty` controls functionality which is managed by the generic terminal driver in the kernel. This driver doesn't handle copy-paste. Copy-paste is an interaction with the environment of the terminal, that's how you can copy-paste not only inside the terminal but also with other program. Copy-paste is provided by the terminal emulator. “Cygwin terminal” isn't precise enough to determine which terminal you're using; check its menus or its documentation to see if the keyboard shortcuts can be configured.

Comment: Reading [your answer on difference between tty, terminal, etc](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4132/214305) and [another about who actually handles clipboard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/750466/4788022), I'm understanding a bit... So `cygwin <--has-- terminal driver <--has-- bash` && `stty` only controls the driver && cygwin plays with clipboard => I should ask cygwin for what I want?

Comment: Wait.. I was lost in all those concepts. See the edited question.

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 You still haven't said which terminal emulator you are using. Cygwin allows you to use many different one. You should ask the terminal emulator for what you want.

Comment: Sorry, the emulator is `mintty`.